# Testing predictability of a predictor of expected weekely returns on the stock market

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, finance, time-series

say I have a T daily observations for the last ten years on a new predictor $x_t$ which I think is a predictor of the expected weekly return on the stock market, $r_{t,t+5} = r_{t+1}+...+r_{t+5}$, where $r_t$ is log return for that period. In this case, how can I test the null hypothesis that $x_t$ has no predictability? The answer would be simple if we are concerned about only one return. But, here, I want to test the predictability for multiple returns which may be correlated with each other. Any idea how to test the hypothesis correctly? What's the correct test statistic and variance of it? Reference to a procedure or an academic paper is also welcome!

Comment: Here's the funny thing: you *won't* actually get reliable statistics on this sort of thing, else you become a hedge fund manager and vanish from publication. The market itself changes over time, and there is no definition that would (1) be statistically rigorous (2) measure something that you actually care about - predicting the *future* market, and (3) have statistical guarantees re:(2) that mean anything.

Comment: @obscurans This is a hypothetical scenario. If such predictor exists, how would I test the hypothesis?